# Azure VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, azure, azure-networking

I have a Virtual Network(VPN Network) with a Virtual Network Gateway, which is connected to VPN instance on AWS using Site-to-Site connection.

Also, I created two networks VNET-A(10.10.0.0/16) and VNET-B(10.20.0.0/16) with peerings connected to VPN Network.

[Network Peering connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeiVF.png)
However, I'm unable to ping instances from AWS network.
Is there something I'm missing?

[Current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsdUs.png)

My goal is to access instances in VNET-A and VNET-B directly from AWS network.

Comment: Please show your route tables in AWS and Azure.

Comment: Hi @RonTrunk, I created a route table for VPNNW GatewaySubnet and added route to 10.10.0.0/16 network with next hop as virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Peering is not transitive, there from traffic from the VPN will need be able to reach the peered network.

You can overcome this by adding custom routes to direct the traffic to the locations you require.

Comment: I need to direct traffic coming into the gateway to their respective networks.
Sorry for noob questions.  I'm totally new to the platform.

Comment: You’ll need to add custom routes to direct the traffic where you want it to go.

Comment: Created a new route table for VPNNW GatewaySubnet and added VNET-A address range to the route table. However, it still doesn't route the traffic.